# Javascript regular expression help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string:

```
User_TimeStamp=20120712201112&email_id=ufe.test20@markit.com&resetCode=**uNcoHR9O3wAAB46xw**&reset=true
```

I tried and Googled a lot to get the highlighted text.  Basically I want a JavaScript regex to get all characters in between `resetCode=` and `&reset=true`.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Why not split on `&`, look for the `resetCode=`, and take the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code where you're looking for the `resetCode` variable

```
var resetCodeValue;
var s = window.location.split('&');
for(var k in s) { var pair = s[k].split('=');
   if (pair[0] == 'resetCode'){
      resetCodeValue = pair[1];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Your regex should be `resetCode=([^&]*)`
2. Split the string on `&` then iterate through each string and split on `=` comparing the first string to `resetCode` and return the second string when you find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something more 'readable':

```
retrieveDesired = User_TimeStamp.split('=')[3].split('&')[0];
```

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/avucut/2/edit)*

Answer (score 0):

why not just use this handy function to get the value of resetCode

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
document.write(getUrlVars()["resetCode"]);
```